# Why does $10 \choose 7$ work in this case?

Tags: combinatorics

On a $10$ question true/false test, if the questions are answered at random, what is the probability of answering exactly $7$ questions correctly?

I see how $10 \choose 7$ would be choosing $7$ correct answers from $10$ possible answers, but how do I account for the $3$ false answers?

Comment: Choosing $7$ correct answers corresponds to choosing $3$ incorrect answers.

Comment: An answer is either true or false. "Choosing 7 correct answers" really means "choosing exactly 7 correct answers", so this accounts for "choosing exactly 3 incorrect answers" as well.

Answer (score 4):

What you actually do is to choose $7$ correct answers from the $10$ and choose $3$ incorrect answers for the remaining $3$. Hence, we get $\binom{10}{7} \binom{3}{3} = \binom{10}{7}$.

Answer (score 1):

$\dbinom{10}{3}$ would be choosing 3 incorrect answers from the 10 possible answers. So the remaining 7 possible answers must be chosen correctly. In general, $\dbinom{n}{r} = \dbinom{n}{n-r}$.

Answer (score 1):

You want to accomplish three things:

1. Choose 7 questions. ($\binom{10}{7}$ ways)
2. Answer those 7 correctly. (probability $0.5$ for each)
3. Answer the remaining questions incorrectly. (probability $0.5$ for each)

Notice you don't need to *pick* the three incorrect answers. You are simply making sure that, once you've answered 7 correctly, all *remaining* questions are false.

Multiplying all that information together gives you a probability of
$$
\binom{10}{7}(0.5)^7(0.5)^3.
$$